# Get json file result dynamically by url parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

if have a json file like this example

market.json

```js
{ topads: 
  [ { id:          114
    , advert_type: 11
    , cat_main_id: 5932
    , cat_market:  1
    , subcat1_id:  12
    , endcat:      'Sneakers'
    , description: 'Nike Air Jordan 1 '
} ] }
```

with php i will get the json file and show all entries with eg subcat1_id 12,15 and 23 (and max. 4 entries)

```php
<?php
  $url_json = $baseurl . 'json/market.json';
  $response = file_get_contents( $url_json );
  $obj      = json_decode( $response, true );

  //subcat1_id
  $ad_types = array( 12,15,23);

  $Count = 0;    
  shuffle($obj[ 'topads' ]);   
  foreach ( $obj[ 'topads' ] as $result ) {
    if ( in_array( $result[ 'subcat1_id' ], $ad_types ) ) {
?>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
        //some html and php content to show the output eg. echo $result[ 'description' ]
      </div>
<?php
      $Count++;
      if ($Count == 4){
        break; //stop foreach loop after 4th loop
      }   
    }
  }
?>
```

ok this works perfectly in php but I want a url parameter (e.g. & `subcat1 = 12`), instead of the hard coded `$ad_types`.
So every time the URL parameter changes, the json file entries should also be displayed dynamically.

But how?

js/jquery

```
<script>
  const subcat1= urlParams.get('subcat1')
</script>
```

to get the url parameter subcat1

and then? Result via Ajax to show the results dynamically?

```js
function getresults() {
      $.ajax({
        url:     "myphpfile.php",
        method:  "POST",
        data:    subcat1,
        success: function (data) {
          // ...
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: data: {subcat1},  data should be {key:value} in ajax request

Answer (score 2):

### Update getresults function with below:

```
function getresults() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "myphpfile.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {subcat1: subcat1},
            success: function (data) {
           }
          });
        }
```

and get in php code like this-

```
$_POST["subcat1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax `data` needs to contain key/value pairs, you are only sending a value

Try :

```
data: {subcat1 :  subcat1 }
```

Then access it in php with:

```
$_POST['subcat1']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.
Thanks for the hints on the solution!

The JS file to get the url parameter dynamically.

```
<script>
// get parameter from url
      var queryString = window.location.search;
      var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      var subcat = urlParams.get('subcat1');
      //console.log(subcat);
      getresult(subcat);

// ajax call
function getresult(subcat) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "myphpfile.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
          "subcat": subcat
        },
        success: function (data) {
   
          $('#ad_content').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
          $('#ad_content').html('error');
        }
      });

    }
</script>
```

and the php file to show the
myphpfile.php

```
<section class="mt-1 mb-1 d-none d-lg-block">
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 pl-0 pr-0">
    <div class="row">
      <?php
      $url_json = '/json/market.json';
      $response = file_get_contents( $url_json );
      $obj = json_decode( $response, true );

      if ( isset( $_POST[ 'subcat' ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ 'subcat' ] ) ) {

        // this is the value from the url parameter
        $adcat = array( $_POST[ 'subcat' ] );

        $Count = 0;
        shuffle( $obj[ 'topads' ] );
        foreach ( $obj[ 'topads' ] as $result ) {
          if ( in_array( $result[ 'subcat1_id' ], $adcat ) ) {
            ?>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="card mb-0"> 
            <?php echo $result[ 'description' ]; ?>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
      $Count++;
      if ( $Count == 4 ) {
        break; //stop foreach loop after 4th loop
      }
      }


      }
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and of course the place to show the result

```
<div id="ad_content"></div>
```

Comment: but there is a function to do this if the author has a solution. no matter .. your hint contributed to the solution and for that I am also grateful!